# How to removeunderline on hover in Submenu in Oracle ADF Alta theme

Tags: java, html, css, oracle-adf

How to remove underline on hover in Submenu in Oracle ADF in [Alta theme](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/middleware/alta/index.html).

I have tried this ADF selector and CSS but it is not working:

```
af|commandMenuItem:hover {
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

and

```
.AFMenuItem:alias {
       text-decoration:none;
    }
```

I have also added costume class but it not works. `background-color` style work but `text-decoration` not working.

Which selector I have to use to remove underline from hover submenu?

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Excuse me, do you mean [this blue line](https://i.gyazo.com/ac9b3df955c7e9b3e75deef75c1d9169.png)? the classes of this button are the following: `oj-navigationlist-item-element oj-navigationlist-item oj-selected`

Comment: in `.oj-selected` you'll see `border-color:#0572ce`